# Creating selection-of from enum?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am looking to create an input-view where the user can pick a list of enum symbols.

For example, I have a finite number of Genres, so I placed them into an enum, these are things such as "Fantasy", and "Sci-fi"

I have tried the code below but nothing displays; I check the documentation but all of the selection-of examples are based off concepts that already have data.

Is there a way to create a selection-of input-view where the user can select one or more items, then outputs this as a concept?

```
input-view {
  match {
    GenreNames(gnames)
  }
  message (Select Genre(s))

  render {
    selection-of (gnames) {
      where-each (one) {
        single-line {
          text {
            value (one)
            style (Detail_M_Soft)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input-view {
  match {
    GenreNames(gnames)
  }
  message (Select Genre(s))

  render {
    selection-of (gnames) {
      where-each (gnames) {
        single-line {
          text {
            value {
              template ("#{value(gnames)}")
            }
            style (Detail_M_Soft)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost! -- The names appear now, but they don't appear to by intractable; -- But they do seem to be selectable, but there is no visual indication that anything is selected. But I can push on some fields and hit "Go" and the fields seem to be tracked.

Comment: If you use the following code, it should look better and inline with the system generated view (for an enum that does not have a custom input-view). 

    cell-card {
      slot2{
        content {
          primary {
            template ("#{value(input1)}")
          }
        }
      }
    }