# Selection of with voice input

Tags: bixby

A raised question from [How can I use selection-of with voice input in a Bixby input-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189529/how-can-i-use-selection-of-with-voice-input-in-a-bixby-input-view). As the answer from this question,

> Currently, there is no keyword support to map "home" as "first one", 
>   if that is what you are asking. However, if you model your JS file to 
>   take "home" as a valid   input argument, and map it to the correct email address,
>   the user can just say "home" during input selection.

For now, is there any way yet to map option for selection-of to input like "first one" that is already been build? And for modelling option in JS file, is there any references for it?

**[Edit]** I find out it can be achieved by adding appropriate training for the concept you related to the option for selection-of, not sure if this is the way. What if user say out word that's similar to the word, where should i add in more option for it? Is it inside a vocabulary file or add unlimited possibilities into js file like this[image] And i think this is kind of related to the discussion in this topic ['Illegal Plan' message when tagging training data with Vocab types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726751/illegal-plan-message-when-tagging-training-data-with-vocab-types)

**Or** should i use enum for each selection as stated in post [How do I match a enum symbol in a result view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206507/how-do-i-match-a-enum-symbol-in-a-result-view) or [Creating selection-of from enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685051/creating-selection-of-from-enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically by adding trainings to prompt, and using enum with vocab, often quiz capsules can get voice input of A, B, C, D mapped correctly, including "Ace, Bee, See" (wrong ASR result from voice).

I would recommend checkout the QuizIt capsule in our marketplace. It is a good example of mapping voice input to the selection-of in input-view.

One downside is the amount of training, developers need to training all the possible input. One implementation is to standardize choice. Consider a board game type of capsule where player are facing choices such as, "You are now standing in front of a door. What would you want to do?" One possible implementation is to do something like this: "Option one: Break open it.", "Option two: turn away", "Option three: try the key you just found" (option three will only present itself if you got a key). Therefore only training and matching "Option X".